# Merging asp.net application with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What all care I need to take when merging an existing Asp.Net 3.5 application with Asp.Net MVC 1.0 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [some](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc) blog [posts](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/MGodfrey/archive/2009/03/31/663.aspx) illustrating how to mix ASP.NET MVC with classic WebForms.